# I can't create stripe token using createTokenWithCard() in React Native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I can integrate Stripe payment method in React Native app. I can use tipsi-stripe package and use createTokenwithCard() method to generate token from server but return null promise.

I am trying different thing but stripe return null promise and i am not understanding why stripe return null promise.

stripe.setOptions({
            publishableKey: '*****************',
            androidPayMode: 'test', 
          })

onVerifyHandler = () =>{

```
const token =  stripe.createTokenWithCard({
    number: '4242424242424242',
    expMonth: 11,
    expYear: 17,
    cvc: '223'});
  console.log(token);
```

}

Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}

Answer (score 3):

You need to let the promise resolve to get the result. Either use an async function:

```
onVerifyHandler = async () => {
  const token = await stripe.createTokenWithCard({
    number: '4242424242424242',
    expMonth: 11,
    expYear: 17,
    cvc: '223'
  });

  console.log(token);
}
```

Or resolve the promise with `then`:

```
onVerifyHandler = () => {
  stripe.createTokenWithCard({
    number: '4242424242424242',
    expMonth: 11,
    expYear: 17,
    cvc: '223'
  }).then(token => {
    console.log(token);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Both ways are not working can you please modify this solution code.

Comment: What isn't working? What have you tried? Are you getting an error? I can't help you if you don't give details.

Comment: when i send my code to stripe .it gives me (Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}) Null Promise. and when i am trying with your code no response from Stripe.